# Create MySQL administrative database users in shared hosting package

Tags: mysql, database, privileges, sql-grant

I have a shared hosting package and MySQL database service. I have some web developers to whom I assign tasks. I want to create a separate database user for each developer.

I want to give each database user the permission of create database, so that they don't need to ask me to create database for each new task. I can't share the cPanel account access. I want to make the database access to restrict to themselves, I don't want them to have access to each other's work, either accidentally or intentionally.

Is there a way for me to create the user that has the privilege to create database for grant the privilege to existing user?

Comment: Voting to migrate to the dba site.

Comment: You should be able to do this via phpMyAdmin, think it's the Privileges tab.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how MySQL is shared and so you should really take this up with your hosting provider. What follows is a basic overview of the concerns and possibilities.

If a MySQL instance is shared across multiple users in a shared hosting service then normally the hosting clients cannot create users, databases, or other global things directly.  In this case, you talk with your hosting provider and they see what they can do for you.

On the other hand if you have a full private instance of MySQL, then you can use any standard tool to do this (phpmyadmin, mysql, etc).  The tools are different so no walkthrough can be offered at this stage.  Again, I would expect your hosting provider to be the first point of contact in a question like this.